# Kentico CMS giving compiler error CS0246

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CMSLoaderAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

> Line 12:     /// Attribute class ensuring correct initialization of
>   methods in macro resolver. Line 13:     ///  Line 14:
>   private class EcommerceModuleLoaderAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute Line
>   15:     { Line 16:         ///
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\KenticoCMS\App_Code\CMSModules\Ecommerce\EcommerceMethodsLoader.cs
>   Line: 14

I have installed Kentico CMS for my website in ASP. Installation was successful and when I tried running the CMS from Visual Studio 2010, Browser showed me the above error.

Comment: Could you tell us which version of Kentico you are using?

Comment: @dvanbale: It would be helpful to know both the current Version and if it was upgraded from another version and/or hotfix.

Comment: I didn't upgrade Kentico...I installed the fresh file from the kentico site ..i.e Kentico CMS 5.5R2

Answer (score 0):

Could you please double check the version? The file mentioned in the error message is new to v6 - it is not present in 5.5R2 installation.

Isn't it possible that you installed v6 over the older 5.5R2 installation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used the same folder and the folder was not empty - the files from version 6 were still there and now they are causing this issue. Could you please clear the folder and install the 5.5R2 version again, into an empty or new folder?